# Is it possible to switch to UK Tier 4 visa from UK tourist visa?

Tags: united-kingdom, student-visa

I am an Indian national going to UK for a course starting in October 2016.The Tier 4 Visa stamped on my passport is starting from September 3.

Now the interesting part is I plan to travel from India to London in August (Tourist Visa)and then fly to Brasil and back to London on 1st September.

My questions are :

a. Will I be allowed entry to UK on a one way ticket on a tourist visa (when i travel in august from India)?
b. Can I enter UK on tourist visa  on 1st september and shift to Tier 4  (somehow)

Fyi : I have booked my tickets already(some schedule constraints) and have been a constant traveller to UK.

Comment: When are the start and end dates for your tourist visa?

Comment: my tourist visa starts 1st week of august until february 2017

Answer (score 1):

No. Tourists cannot stay and switch to other types of visas. You have to go home first.

Source:

> If you come to the UK with permission as a visitor, you cannot apply to switch to a student category in the UK, you will need to return home to apply for permission to study.

[src](http://www.lse.ac.uk/study/informationForInternationalStudents/visasAndImmigration/ifYouHaveANon-StudentVisa.aspx)

Also, somebody arriving on a tourist visa with no return ticket is something they look out for. I have a sneaking suspicion you'd have your visa revoked.

Comment: I think the OP already has the student visa, so returning home is not the issue at hand here.

Comment: yes i already have both tourist and student visa stamped on my passport.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I was able to fly straight back to UK from Brazil. They just want the visa stamped on your passport.